# TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' when using seasonal_decompose from statsmodel

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

Using weekly import data, I am trying to use seasonal_decompose to analyze some data but I am getting the following error:    if not np.all(np.isfinite(x)):

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose



PADD2_imports = pd.read_csv('PADD 2 Imports.csv')


PADD2_imports['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(PADD2_imports['Date'])
PADD2_imports['KBD Imports'] = PADD2_imports['KBD Imports'].astype(float)


decomposition = seasonal_decompose(PADD2_imports, model='additive', freq=52).plot()
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
if not np.all(np.isfinite(x)):

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```